# Cellular Connection not showing up

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet

Good day,

I have a Thinkpad T495, which comes with a builtin SIM card slot. I tried following [these](https://ubuntu.com/core/docs/networkmanager/configure-cellular-connections) instructions, but when i run

```
sudo modem-manager.mmcli -L
```

i get

```
error: couldn't get bus: Could not connect: Permission denied
```

Also, Cellular Connection doesn`t show up as an option in my network settings, even with a SIM card installed.

Comment: If the sim card can not be accessed of course it will not show up. That doc says it is for Ubuntu Core are you sure it works the same on your unstated version of Ubuntu?

Comment: I was hoping it would work the same on my 22.04.2 LTS. Also, what do you mean by the SIM card can`t be accessed?

Comment: From your question, can not be accessed. error: couldn't get bus: Could not connect: Permission denied